# problema con tamaño de imagen, no abarca el componente padre

Tags: html, css

buen día a todos;

Estoy haciendo una plantilla con el elemento tabla con 5 columnas, con un ancho definido en porcentajes a 20% cada 1 y en algunas celdas tengo que insertar imágenes.

El problema es que si la imagen es muy grande hace que la celda se expanda y por tanto también la columna entera y me perjudica en otras cosas (lo cual creo que solucione insertando la imagen como fondo de la celda y no con un elemento IMG dentro de la celda y así evitar que modifique el tamaño de la columna)

```
#celda4{ 
         background-image: url("'.$urlImgPrincipal.'");  
         background-size: cover;
    }
```

Pero ahora el problema es que si la imagen es mas grande que la celda, solo se muestra una porción de la imagen

lo que muestra la celda:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como es en realidad toda la imagén:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que la imagen al ponerla de fondo de la celda se adapte al tamaño y se pueda ver toda  pero no se como.
O en caso ¿Como puedo obtener el tamaño de la celda antes de dimensionar un elemento **img** que este dentro de este?  para así asignarle un tamaño al **img** en su **width  y height** correspondientes a la celda

Comment: O sea ¿Quieres que la imagen se deforme? Porque si no cabe en la celda, pero tampoco quieres que la celda se agrande, no sé cómo le quieres hacer. ¿Probaste `background-size: contain`?

Comment: Buenas noches, siempre es mejor si pasas al menos el mínimo código necesario para poder hacer pruebas, en cuanto a la imagen si la pones como img en el contenedor y le das un width de 100% a la imagen debería ser suficiente para que esta se adapte al ancho de su padre..

Comment: Como dice Luis S. Romero si pones una parte del código donde podamos apreciar lo que quieres hacer es más fácil replicar el comportamiento y ayudar te. saludos,